# How do I assign the values of an object array to another object array that has more properties?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, ionic-framework

I am taking an array of `Workouts` and want to turn it into an array of `RoutineWorkouts` which has all of the properties of `Workouts` as well as `"sets"` and `"reps"`. Then I want to display this array as a list on [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk1Nn.png) where I will be able to assign the reps and sets with `ion-select`.

**create-routine.page.ts**

```
 workoutR: any[];
 routineWorkouts: RoutineWorkout[] = [];
 sets = [2, 3, 4];
 reps = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 16, 20];

ionViewWillEnter(): void{
   this._subscription = this.workoutService.getMessage().subscribe((bWorkout:Workout[]) => {
     this._receivedWorkouts = bWorkout;
   });
   console.log(this._receivedWorkouts);
   this.workoutR = this._receivedWorkouts;  
 }
```

To display it on the page, I have `*ngFor="let workout of workoutR"`.

**Workout and RoutineWorkout models**

```
export class Workout {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    muscle: string;
}
export class RoutineWorkout {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    sets: number;
    reps: number;
}
```

I have tried [this, but keep getting this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoZtT.png)
How would I assign the values of the array that I created as new `RoutineWorkouts` so that I can assign reps and sets?

Comment: `RoutineWorkouts` has all of the properties of Workouts as well as `"sets"` and `"reps"`. This is not correct `RoutineWorkout` doenot contain `muscle` which is part of `Workout`.

Comment: `this._receivedWorkouts = bWorkout;` this is not possible. You are trying to assign a variable to another having different interfaces. This can be done with some work around after understanding the requirement.

Comment: So how do you expect this to happen? Is it like you want to take `id` and `name` from `Workout` and set `sets` and `reps` as `0`?

Comment: Yes, I would like to create a new array of `RoutineWorkouts` with the `id` and `name` of `Workout`, from the existing array of `Workouts`. The `sets` and `reps` would be `0` until I assign them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign a variable of one type(Interface) to another. Instead you can create a new variable with same type and assign them back to the required one.

Here `this.routineWorkouts` is of Interface `RoutineWorkout[]` and `this._receivedWorkouts` is of type `Workout[]`

**Pseude Code**

```
const newReceivedWorkouts: RoutineWorkout[] = this._receivedWorkouts.map(({id, name}) => ({ id, name, sets: 0, reps: 0}))
this.routineWorkouts = newReceivedWorkouts;
```

Here `this.routineWorkouts` and `newReceivedWorkouts` are of same type, hence they are assignable.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Before your answer I actually came up with this: `this.receivedWorkouts.map(item => { return {id: item.id, name: item.name, sets: 0, reps: 0 }}).forEach(item => this.routineWorkouts.push(item));` and it worked! I tried out your code as well and it also worked. I'll stick with the one I just figured out because I understand how I made it, but your answer is more helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You are welome. Self learning will always help you to understand the concepts.